# ¿Cómo agregar combobox en un submenu en java?

Tags: java, java-swing, combobox

estoy tratando de implementar un combobox para elegir un tamaño de fuente para una aplicación. Necesito crear un menú de opciones, y un submenú que muestre el combobox con los posibles tamaños. Pero al ir a escoger un numero, el submenu se esconde y la barra de desplazamiento no funciona. La clase extiende de un JMenuBar.

Este es el código:

```
    JMenu jMenuTriangle1 = new JMenu("Opciones");
    JMenu Submenu = new JMenu("Tamaño de fuente");
    JComboBox<String> jComboBox = new JComboBox<>();

    jComboBox.addItem("1");
    jComboBox.addItem("2");
    jComboBox.addItem("3");
    jComboBox.addItem("4");
    jComboBox.addItem("5");
    jComboBox.addItem("6");
    jComboBox.addItem("7");
    jComboBox.addItem("8");
    jComboBox.addItem("9");
    jComboBox.addItem("10");
    jComboBox.addItem("11");
    jComboBox.addItem("12");
    jComboBox.addItem("13");
    Submenu.add(jComboBox);
    jMenuTriangle1.add(Submenu);
    this.add(jMenuTriangle1);
```

Esta es la imagen, lo que llevo hasta el momento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: Se esconde el submenú y la barra de desplazamiento no funciona]

Answer (score 0):

hay 2 opciones:

1. En lugar de agregar un comboBox al jMenu, puedes ingresar varios jmenuItem:

Ejemplo:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < size ; i++) {
        JmenuFuente.add(new JMenuItem(String.valueOf(i))); //agrega al tamaño de fuente opciones hasta el 13
        JmenuFuente.addSeparator();//agrega una linea de separacion al menu
    }
```

De esta forma evitas esto:

```
    jComboBox.addItem("1");
    jComboBox.addItem("2");
    jComboBox.addItem("3");
    jComboBox.addItem("4");
    jComboBox.addItem("5");
    jComboBox.addItem("6");
    jComboBox.addItem("7");
    jComboBox.addItem("8");
    jComboBox.addItem("9");
    jComboBox.addItem("10");
    jComboBox.addItem("11");
    jComboBox.addItem("12");
    jComboBox.addItem("13");
```

Y te queda algo asi:

[image: opcion 1 imagen]

2. Otra opción un poco mas compleja, te permite crear un dialogo aparte que recibe un arreglo con las opciones que desees(en caso que no necesites números, sino palabras):

Ejemplo:

```
    String[] items = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10,","11","12","13"}; 
    JMenuBar jMenuBar = new JMenuBar();//Barra de menu
    JMenu JmenuOpciones = new JMenu("Opciones"); //menu de opciones
    JMenuItem jmenuItemFuente = new JMenuItem("Tamaño de fuente..."); //opcion que abre el dialogo de fuentes
    jmenuItemFuente.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {//metodo que recibe el evento del boton
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            showNumber(); // abrir el dialogo
        }
    });

   public void showNumber() {
    String result = String.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, //componente padre
            "Titulo del dialogo", //titulo del dialogo
            "Ingrese el tamaño de fuente:", //mensaje de muestra
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, // icono del mensaje
            null, // icono del dialogo
            items, //opciones a mostrar
            items[0])); //opcion inicial
    System.out.println("el numero obtenido fue: " + result);
}
```

esta opcion te mostrara algo asi:

[image: opcion 2 visualizacion]